# Wildfly: disable persistence unit lookup

Tags: jpa, deployment, persistence, wildfly, kundera

At the very beginning of artifact deploy, Wildfly validates all persistence unit described in persistence.xml. One on the responsible classes is `org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitServiceHandler` from `wildfly-jpa` library.

The main question: is it possible to disable this validation somehow? Or just mark persistence unit as ignored?

**Details an root cause:**

We are going to build environment-free artifacts. So the configuration inside persistence.xml will be overridden in java code at the very beginning. Default configuration is dummy and looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="cassandra_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
    <class>sample.model.Manager</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="kundera.port" value="9165"/>
        <property name="kundera.username" value="test"/>
        <property name="kundera.password" value="test"/>
        <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="keyspace"/>
        <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra"/>
        <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.kundera.client.cassandra.dsdriver.DSClientFactory"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

But wildfly validates persistence units and calls `KunderaPersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory`. Kundera in it's turn checks connection against localhost:9165 and fails. So deployment fails too.

Any workaround is acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully, I found solution.
Need to add

```
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false"/>
```

into persistence.xml. Wildfly will ignore persistence unit on startup.

And it will possible to initialize it manually via

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cassandra_unit", kunderaProperties)
```

and apply all required override logic.

Hope this will save someone's life )

Seed more wildfly-specific properties at `org.jboss.as.jpa.config.Configuration` class inside `wildfly-jpa` jar